# How do I make Selenium find elements with varying ID?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to make a simple script which will create an email account at the url: https://service.mail.com/registration.html

Each time I reload the page, the input text fields have a different ID. How do I locate these elements reliably ? Also, why would someone want to change the ID all the time ?

Example:

```
<input class="Text ColouredFocus" type="text" value="" name="z1085243925" id="id11b" maxlength="30" onchange="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('?wicket:interface=:4:FormRegistration:ListRegistrationData:0:ItemRegistrationData:BorderBoxRegistrationData:PanelRegistrationData:Row1:Field::IBehaviorListener:1:', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('id11b')),function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('id11b') != null;}.bind(this));" tabindex="1">
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to always use `id` or `name` attributes. There is an enormous amount of techniques and location strategies. Choosing one sometimes is not that trivial as it might seem.

For instance, in this case, from my perspective, a readable and a reliable way to locate the input fields would be to rely on the class names of the `li` parents. Sample for the last name:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".userdata-lastname input"));
```

Comment: Is this also okay ?  @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = ".userdata-lastname input")
 WebElement firstNameInput;

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore almost, for the first name the selector would be `.userdata-firstname input`.

Comment: it looks like space is there before input so '.' is not required? like .userdata-lastname.input

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer from what I see, the `.userdata-lastname input` with a space in between should work in this case - we are basically searching for the `input` element under an element having `userdata-lastname` class. Hope that helps.